# Having trouble setting cookie via AJAX login with Yii2

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, yii, yii2

I'm using `Yii2` and I have setup a login process which works fine (cookies as well) via the standard login page which is *not* `AJAX`.

I have built a dropdown login field which works fine at logging them in, however it doesn't seem to set the cookie as the user doesn't stay logged in and there is no bookie created.

I figured that this was because of AJAX and the cookie wasn't being created on the users system, but upon further reading it seems it *should* work.

I have verified that the cookie value is being set correctly, the only issue is the cookie doesn't seem to being created.

**My login code:**

JS:

```
function doLogin() {

    // Set file to prepare our data
    var loadUrl = "../../user/login/";

    // Set parameters
    var dataObject = $('#login_form').serialize();

    // Set status element holder
    var status_el = $('#login_status');

    // Make sure status element is hidden
    status_el.hide();

    // Run request

    getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, 'POST', 'json')

            .done(function(response) {

                if (response.result == 'success') {

                    //.......

                } else {

                    //.......

                }

            })

            .fail(function() {
                //.......
            });

    // End

}

function getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, action, type) {

    if ($('meta[name="csrf-token"]').length) {
        // Add our CSRF token to our data object
        dataObject._csrf = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    }

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: action,
        url: loadUrl,
        data: dataObject,
        dataType: type
    });

}
```

Controller:

```
public function actionLogin() {

    // Check if they already logged in

    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest and !Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        // Set our data holder
        $response = ['output' => '', 'result' => 'error'];
    }

    // Let's send the POST data to the model and see if their login was valid

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax and $this->user->validate() and $this->user->login()) {

        $response['result'] = 'success';

    } elseif (!Yii::$app->request->isAjax and Yii::$app->request->isPost and $this->user->validate() and $this->user->login()) {

        //.......

    } else {

        //.......

    }

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        echo Json::encode($response);
    }

}
```

Model:

```
public function login() {

    // Set cookie expire time
    $cookie_expire = 3600 * 24 * Yii::$app->params['settings']['cookie_expire'];

    return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), ($this->remember_me ? $cookie_expire : 0));

}
```

Comment: do you set cookie for same domain?

Comment: @mmta41 Yes, I let Yii handle that and it sets it to the correct domain when it sets the cookie successfully via the standard process.

Comment: Just a quick thought - does it help if you replace the content of the last `if`brackets with `Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON; return $response;`

Comment: @Bizley Oh wow - that worked! You da man! :) Please post as an answer so I can accept and reward you the bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected (see my earlier comment) response might not be correctly generated in case of simply echoing the data. Or maybe `Content-Type` header matters. If someone can confirm this it will be great.

Anyway, I'm glad it works now (data needs to be `returned`).

And you can use `Response` handy `format` as well.

```
public function actionLogin() {

    // ...

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        return $response;
    }
}
```